# Can Thunderbird delete a large number ( 100k ) of emails from an IMAP folder?

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I have a folder on an imap server which contains ~100k emails and trying to select them all and press delete seems to crash thunderbird (7.

Is there any way i can delete these messages from thunderbird?

Comment: Other people who got assaulted at thier e-mail server similarly, who's mail clents could not even access it without crashing, would contact the people running the server, and ask them to fix it there. Myself I would try a macro and 100 at a time, before I gave up.

Comment: I've managed to delete them by doing a few times: select all ( ctrl+a ) then delete ( del ) then wait for crash, click restart tb. Was hoping for an extension or something like move all messages to trash on the context menu of a folder.

Comment: Sounds like a case where the admin of your imap server can help you. Through the shell it's extremely easy to delete everything from a folder.

Answer (score 0):

There were several memory management bugs in Thunderbird associated with performing actions on very large batches of emails. I think newer builds have many of these bugs fixed so try the newest build of TB and see if that helps.

- Look through comments of [bug 398684](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=398684) for more details.